# Displaying dates as holiday in WPF Calendar

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm using  WPF Calendar control to add Holidays. User can select days and the selected days will be  inserted to a database table as holiday. 
After the insertion, I'm displaying the days in Holiday table as `BlackoutDates` in the calendar as in the following code.

**XAML**

```
 <Calendar x:Name="HolidayCalendar" SelectedDatesChanged="Calendar_SelectionChanged"
    SelectionMode="MultipleRange" Loaded="Calendar_Loaded">
```

**C#**

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
GetHolidayService getHolidayService = new GetHolidayService();
ObservableCollection<GetHoliday> GetHolidayBaseList = new ObservableCollection<GetHoliday>();
PostHoliday postHoliday = new PostHoliday();
postHoliday.StartDate = startDate;
postHoliday.EndDate = endDate;
GetHolidayBaseList = getHolidayService.GetHolidayServiceFunction(postHoliday);
foreach (var item in GetHolidayList)
{

   HolidayCalendar.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(item.HolidayDate,item.HolidayDate)) ;
}
```

**Current output**

[image: Current output]

**I want to achieve something like this** - Holidays marked as Red

[image: Preferred output]

as in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx)

Any help to write a control template required for this functionality is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, I've edited my question. Will you please refer it again? Is my question clear now?

Comment: I want to display Holidays as different, something like I mentioned in the picture (holidays marked as red). If  I'm adding holidays to SelectedDates, if my user selects some new date, user can't differentiate SelectedDates from Holidays. That's why. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it,

First define custom style for CalendarDataButton based on standard style

```
    <Calendar x:Name="HolidayCalendar" SelectionMode="MultipleRange">
        <Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
            <Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CalendarDayButton}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsBlackedOut" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DeepPink"/>
                        <Setter Property="local:CalenderHelper.IsBlackOutDisabled" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Calendar.CalendarDayButtonStyle>
        <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
            <CalendarDateRange Start="21-Nov-2018" End="21-Nov-2018"/>
            <CalendarDateRange Start="25-Nov-2018" End="25-Nov-2018"/>
        </Calendar.BlackoutDates>
    </Calendar>
```

In order to remove the strike mark from Blackout date, you will have to use the below attached property 'IsBlackOutDisabled'

```
public class CalenderHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBlackOutDisabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsBlackOutDisabled", typeof(bool), typeof(CalenderHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBlackOutDisabledChanged));

    public static bool GetIsBlackOutDisabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsBlackOutDisabledProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsBlackOutDisabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsBlackOutDisabledProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsBlackOutDisabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CalendarDayButton dayButton = d as CalendarDayButton;
        if (dayButton.IsLoaded)
        {
            SetBlackout(dayButton, (bool)e.NewValue);
        }
        else
        {
            dayButton.Loaded += (s, ee) =>
            {
                SetBlackout(dayButton, (bool)e.NewValue);
            };
        }
    }

    static void SetBlackout(CalendarDayButton dayButton, bool collapsed)
    {
        ControlTemplate template = dayButton.Template;
        Path blackoutPath = template.FindName("Blackout", dayButton) as Path;
        if (collapsed)
            blackoutPath.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            blackoutPath.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want the colored dates to be selectable by Calendar, you must go with different approach. Blackout Dates will not work for you.

This approach takes the converter to color the dates.

First define custom style for CalendarDataButton based on standard style

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CustomLetterDayConverter x:Key="CustomLetterDayConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CustomLetterDayConverter}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Calendar x:Name="HolidayCalendar" SelectionMode="MultipleRange" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}"
              CalendarDayButtonStyle="{StaticResource CalendarDayButtonStyle}"
              >
    </Calendar>
</Grid>
```

The custom converter

```
public class CustomLetterDayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    static HashSet<DateTime> dict = new HashSet<DateTime>();
    static CustomLetterDayConverter()
    {
        dict.Add(DateTime.Today);
        dict.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
        dict.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(2));
        dict.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(5));
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = null;
        if (dict.Contains((DateTime)value))
            text = null;
        else
            text = "";

        return text;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to select blackoutdates or can non selectable property of blackoutdate overridden?

Comment: See my updates above to handle you scenario. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I think this is not the solution. My `GetHolidayBaseList` is changing dynamically and I need to render the dynamic changes on the calendar. The current solution will set some random days in HotPink color, but what I want is apply color dynamically. For example: If the user changes the month to october (currently displayed month is november), then `GetHolidayBaseList` will have the holidays in October, but I need to update that on the Calendar display.

Comment: You can set the calendar template property to null and then reapply the template. That will force the styling to update.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pure XAML, using Visual states :

```
<Style TargetType="CalendarDayButton" x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".35" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup Name="ActiveStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="Active" />
                            <VisualState Name="Inactive">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="#FFCBCBCB" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup Name="DayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState Name="RegularDay" />
                            <VisualState Name="Today">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="#FFFFFFFF" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState Name="BlackoutDay">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".35" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="TodayBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="Blue"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="Silver"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="LightGray"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,1,5,1" TextElement.Foreground="Black"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    
</Style>
```

Solution lies in defining own ControlTemplate with It's visual states. Most important thing is inside **VisualStateGroup "DayStates"** - VisualState with name **"BlackoutDay"**.

This way no attached properties is needed for overriding default blackout style, and all sorts of button colors for each control's state can be completely customized.