# To add an ellipse inside date button (Clickable) in calendar control to represent special dates in WPF

Tags: wpf, calendar

**Goal:** To add a small dot(ellipse) under any special date and also it should be selectable. Idea is to pass a specific date then draw this ellipse under that day.

**Progress:** I added the ellipse under the date.

Please check the code if it is correct.

**Xaml:**

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <local:CustomLetterDayConverter x:Key="CustomLetterDayConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="CalendarDayButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CustomLetterDayConverter}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDayButton">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                        <Ellipse Height="5" Width="5" Fill="Silver" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Calendar x:Name="HolidayCalendar" SelectionMode="MultipleRange" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" 
              CalendarDayButtonStyle="{StaticResource CalendarDayButtonStyle}"
              >
            <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
                <CalendarDateRange Start="01-09-2020" End="05-09-2020"/>
            </Calendar.BlackoutDates>
        </Calendar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    public class CustomLetterDayConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        static HashSet<DateTime> dict = new HashSet<DateTime>();
        static CustomLetterDayConverter()
        {
            dict.Add(DateTime.Today);
            dict.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
            dict.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(2));
            dict.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(5));
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string text = null;
            if (dict.Contains((DateTime)value))
                text = null;
            else
                text = "";

            return text;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

[Solution Tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371091/displaying-dates-as-holiday-in-wpf-calendar)

Following this solution I was able to add the special dates. But it is not selectable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you override the `Template` of a control, you're taking responsibility of implementing all the visual states that the control requires.

In your case, you've only implemented a `ContentPresenter` and your `Ellipse`, there are no triggers to handle the many other visual states of the `CalendarDayButton`.

To see what you need to implement, you should use Blend for Visual Studio, add a Calendar control to a sample project, and then extract the control templates, so you can see a full reference template.